# How to get spring context from maven module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, multi-module

I'm having an issue trying to make test in my spring-boot project.

[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhHdf.png)

as you can see, my project is devided with maven modules.
"alta-launcher" is the "main" project getting every other module as dependencies.
The problem is that my tests in the user module won't get the spring context so my fields "Autowired" will be null on runtime.

Any ideas how to configure this project to be able to do tests in each modules ?

Edit :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = CoreApplication.class)
class UserQueryTransformerImplTest {
@Autowired
private UserQueryTransformer userQueryTransformer;

@Test
void toDTO() {
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setLogin("everest");
    userEntity.setFirstName("Everest");
    userEntity.setLastName("Mountain");
    UserQueryDTO userQueryDTO = userQueryTransformer.toDTO(userEntity);

    assertEquals(userEntity.getLogin(), userQueryDTO.getLogin());
    assertEquals(userEntity.getFirstName(), userQueryDTO.getFirstName());
    assertEquals(userEntity.getLastName(), userQueryDTO.getLastName());
}
```

The annotation @SpringBootTest with the attribute classes is unusable because I don't have access to the launcher module from user module. And without the attribute (juste @SprinBootTest) is when I'm getting my autowire field null which makes sense cause I don't have the context.

Comment: Go through the docs : https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/ . It covers almost everything that you might need!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already been through this doc several times and it's not helping in my case... My project is devided in modules that are my domains, the module launcher is getting the others modules as dependency so I don't have the context from those modules :(

Comment: Your autowired field cannot be `null`. Your application or test would blow up with an `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` instead. So if they are `null` you are doing things wrong (not using Spring to run your test, creating instances yourself etc. ). However as you only posted an image of your project structure and you didn't add your actual test, that is impossible to tell.

Comment: I edited my post so that you can have more informations. Hope it helps

Comment: You cannot include a Spring Boot jar as a dependency in another project. A Spring BOot fat jar has a different structure (due to customized loading of classes) and as such the classes arent' available. If you really want this you will have to deliver 2 artifacts 1 fatjar and a non-fatjar (a regular jar) containing the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by using ContextConfiguration annotation.
(ExtendWith is for the junit5 part)

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigurationTest.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class UserQueryTransformerImplTest {
@Autowired
private UserQueryTransformer userQueryTransformer;

@Test
void toDTO() {
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setLogin("everest");
    userEntity.setFirstName("Everest");
    userEntity.setLastName("Mountain");
    UserQueryDTO userQueryDTO = userQueryTransformer.toDTO(userEntity);

    assertEquals(userEntity.getLogin(), userQueryDTO.getLogin());
    assertEquals(userEntity.getFirstName(), userQueryDTO.getFirstName());
    assertEquals(userEntity.getLastName(), userQueryDTO.getLastName());
}
```

and here is my configurationTest.java

```
@TestConfiguration
public class ConfigurationTest {

@Bean
UserQueryTransformer createUserQueryTransformer() {
    return new UserQueryTransformerImpl();
}

@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
UserQueryDTO createUserQueryDTO() {
    return new UserQueryDTO();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate your custom context in tests, try something like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class UserQueryTransformerImplTest {
@TestConfiguration
static class Config {
  @Bean
  public UserQueryTransformer uqt() {
     return new UserQueryTransformer();
  }
}
@Autowired
private UserQueryTransformer userQueryTransformer;

@Test
void toDTO() {
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setLogin("everest");
    userEntity.setFirstName("Everest");
    userEntity.setLastName("Mountain");
    UserQueryDTO userQueryDTO = userQueryTransformer.toDTO(userEntity);

    assertEquals(userEntity.getLogin(), userQueryDTO.getLogin());
    assertEquals(userEntity.getFirstName(), userQueryDTO.getFirstName());
    assertEquals(userEntity.getLastName(), userQueryDTO.getLastName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's still not working, I tried the nested class and the import. With the nested class my autowired is still null. With the import I'm getting an IllegalStateException : Unable to find a SpringBootConfiguration ...

Comment: Actually it's more like when i'm using SpringBootTest, I'm getting the illegalStateException and if i'm not using it, the autowired is null. Looks like it really doesnt care about the TestConfiguration (nested or import)

Comment: Hi, try to add @ContextConfiguration annotation.